# Angular FormControl Validator Min initialized with variable does not update with variable changes

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms, material-components

I'm using Angular 8 and Material Components and want to restrict a value **b** to be greater than or equal to value **a** in a form using the min validator. I use two material inputs with a shared form control and bind them to parameters of a **shared** object. In my controller, I define the validator for **b**'s form control as `min(shared.a)`, assuming that with changes to **shared.a**, also the validator should be updated. For example, after setting **a** to 4 via the input, **b** should be invalid unless >= 4. However, the validator does not update with changes made to **a** but seems to be static with the initial value of **a**. What am I missing?

`example.component.html`:

```html
<form [formGroup]="exampleForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type=number formControlName="a" [(ngModel)]="shared.a">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput type=number formControlName="b" [(ngModel)]="shared.b">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

and `example.component.ts`:

```js
export class Example implements OnInit {
  shared = {'a': 0, 'b': 1}
  exampleForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.exampleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      a: [this.shared.a, Validators.min(0)],
      b: [this.shared.b, Validators.min(this.shared.a)]
    })
  }
}
```

[Minimal working example on Stackblitz](https://angular-bu9ytx.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Yes this won’t work (unfortunately). A validator only triggers when the value it belongs to changes. Also, the value you give the validator is only used for initialization. You can solve this by using a group validator, which will trigger when any of the controls of the group change.

Comment: That's unfortunate! But thanks for the suggestion, haven't thought of it yet (since I thought I didn't have to :D).